# How to bind bluetooth headset control clicks with hammerspoon?

Tags: macos, lua, hammerspoon

I am trying to detect `eventtaps` on my bluetooth headset and write some custom logic using Hammerspoon [hs.eventtap](https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.eventtap.html) module. Following is a minimal code snippet in `init.lua`:

```
function mediaKeyCallback(event)
    print(event:getType())
end
eventtap = hs.eventtap.new({
    hs.eventtap.event.types.gesture,
  }, mediaKeyCallback)
eventtap:start()
```

If I change the volume from the touch bar, there are events logged. However, when doing the same from the headset, the volume indeed changes, but the event is not caught by Hammerspoon. I tried to use `hs.eventtap.event.types.systemDefined` and `hs.eventtap.event.types.NSSystemDefined` without any success. Should I be using some other Hammerspoon module or am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: did you find a solution for this ? I'm interested in remapping one of my headset function